# Acceptable use of os.open/read/write/close?

Tags: python, file

I intend to frequently read/write small pieces of information from many different files. The following somewhat contrived example shows substantially less time taken when using `os` operations for acting directly on file descriptors. Am I missing any downside other than the convenience of file objects?

```
import os
import time

N = 10000
PATH = "/tmp/foo.test"

def testOpen():
    for i in range(N):
        with open(PATH, "wb") as fh:
            fh.write("A")

    for i in range(N):
        with open(PATH, "rb") as fh:
            s = fh.read()

def testOsOpen():
    for i in range(N):
        fd = os.open(PATH, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
        try:
            os.write(fd, "A")
        finally:
            os.close(fd)

    for i in range(N):
        fd = os.open(PATH, os.O_RDONLY)
        try:
            s = os.read(fd, 1)
        finally:
            os.close(fd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for fn in testOpen, testOsOpen:
        start = time.time()
        fn()
        print fn.func_name, "took", time.time() - start
```

Sample run:

```
$ python bench.py 
testOpen took 1.82302999496
testOsOpen took 0.436559915543
```

Comment: what version of python?

Comment: @user2682863, it must be Python 2 - in Python 3 the low-level IO ops require and return "bytes-like objects" rather than strings.  That is, this code won't run under Py3.

Comment: I am using 2, but am curious if there are noteworthy differences in 3.

Comment: I was more curious of what version of 2. I know they made a lot of improvements to read/write speed in recent versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer just so this doesn't stay open forever ;-)

There's really little to say:  as you already noted, a `file` object is more convenient.  In *some* cases it's also more functional; for example, it does its own layer of buffering to speed line-oriented text operations (like `file_object.readline()`) (BTW, that's one reason it's slower too.)  And a `file` object strives to work the same way across all platforms.

But if you don't need/want that, there's nothing at all wrong with using the lower-level & zippier `os` file descriptor functions instead.  There are many of the latter, and not all are supported on all platforms, and not all options are supported on all platforms.  Of course you're responsible for restricting yourself to a subset of operations & options in the intersection of the platforms you care about (which is generally true of all functions in `os`, not just its file descriptor functions - the name `os` is a strong hint that the stuff it contains may be OS-dependent).

With respect to Pythons 2 and 3, the differences are due to the strong distinction Python 3 makes between "text" and "binary" modes on *all* platforms.  It's a Unicode world, and "text mode" for `file` objects make no sense without specifying the intended encoding.  In Python 3, a `file` object read method returns a `str` object (a Unicode string) if the file was opened in "text mode", but a `bytes` object if in "binary mode".  Similarly for write methods.

Because the `os` file descriptor methods have no notion of encoding, they can only work with bytes-like objects in Python 3 (regardless of whether, e.g., on Windows, the file descriptor was opened with the low-level `os.open()` `O_BINARY` or `O_TEXT` flags).

In practice, in the example you gave, this just means you would have to change instances of

```
"A"
```

to

```
b"A"
```

Note that you can also use the `b"..."` literal syntax in a recent-enough version of Python 2, although it's still just a string literal in Python 2.  In Python 3 it denotes a different kind of object (`bytes`), and file descriptor functions are restricted to writing and returning bytes-like objects.

But if you're working with "binary data", that's no restriction at all.  If you're working with "text data", it *may* be (not enough info about your specifics to guess).

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I appreciate the insight from someone who has been heavily involved with Python for so long. I am working with binary data using ``struct``. I am just looking for a no-frills way to store and retrieve integers as fast as reasonably possible, and the performance penalty of first class ``file`` objects seemed fairly high without any benefit for my use case. Although I am beginning to think that if I care so much about performance, I should just use C.

Comment: The more important speed is, the _longer_ I stick to pure Python ;-)  Only partly joking there:  Python can be so slow that sticking to Python forces me to come up with _fundamentally_ better approaches.  For example, maybe what you "really" need is a database, or a clever use of dicts, or ...  On the face of it, opening and closing a file just to change a few bytes is unpromising:  regardless of language, that's high overhead for little work accomplished.  And trying other approaches is a lot easier the longer you stick to Python :-)